# NoMethodError at /users: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I know this is probably the most discussed error on Stack, and I've been sifting through other questions/answers for hours, unable to fix it. I'm sure the fix is simple and right in front of me, but I'm new and slightly overwhelmed. I'll appreciate any guidance.

I'm getting "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass" when creating a customer for my app, after the user's info has been verified and the credit card has been processed/approved.

I'm using Stripe and the error is first called in my StripeWrapper (email: options[:user].email,):

```
class Customer
 attr_reader :response, :error_message

 def initialize(options={})
   @response = options[:response]
   @error_message = options[:error_message]
 end

 def self.create(options={})
   begin
     response = Stripe::Customer.create(
       card: options[:card],
       email: options[:user].email,
       plan: "base"
     )
     new(response: response)
   rescue Stripe::CardError => e
     new(error_message: e.message)
   end
 end

 def successful?
   response.present?
 end

 def customer_token
   response.id
 end
```

end

Then again in my UserSignup object (customer = StripeWrapper::Customer.create):

```
def initialize(user)
  @user = user
end

def sign_up(stripe_token, invitation_token)
  if @user.valid?
    customer = StripeWrapper::Customer.create(
      :amount => 999, # amount in cents  currency is hardcoded in wrapper
      :card => stripe_token,
      :description => "Subscribtion charge for #{@user.email}"
    )
    if customer.successful?
      @user.customer_token = customer.customer_token
      @user.save
      handle_invitation(invitation_token)
      AppMailer.send_welcome_email(@user).deliver
      @status = :success
      self
    else
      @status = :failed
      @error_message = customer.error_message
      self
    end
  else
    @status = :failed
    @error_message = "Invalid user information. Please check your info."
    self
  end
end
```

And also in my UsersController 
(result = UserSignup.new(@user).sign_up(params[:stripeToken],params[:invitation_token]):

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    result = UserSignup.new(@user).sign_up(params[:stripeToken],     params[:invitation_token])
    if result.successful?
      flash[:success] = "Thank you for registering! Please sign in."
      redirect_to sign_in_path
    else
      flash[:error] = result.error_message
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Well, after lots of experimentation, I made it work. 
In the StripeWrapper I changed

```
email: options[:user].email
```

to

```
email: options[:stripeEmail]
```

and also added stripeEmail as a parameter in UserSignup def signup.

I only came across stripeEmail while digging through my logs to better understand the error.